# Discord.JS TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

Tags: events, discord, discord.js, typeerror, handler

Good Morning! I am currently working on a discord bot but I am facing an issue with the **event handlers**.
There seems to be a problem with the "**get**" command but I can't seem to find out what it
is, I have given the code below to my **message.js**

```
module.exports = (Discord, client, msg) => {

    const prefix = 'e!';

    if (!msg.content.startsWith(prefix) || msg.author.bot) return;

    const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const cmd = client.commands.get(command)

    if (!cmd){
        msg.channel.send("That is not an available command!")
    };

    if(command) command.execute(client, msg, args, Discord);
};
```

The code below is my **index.js**

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client({intents : ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"]});
const button = require('discord-buttons')(client)
const { MessageButton } = require("discord-buttons")
 
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();

['command_handler', 'event_handler'].forEach(handler =>{
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord);
})

client.login(process.env.token)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It means `client.commands` is `undefined`. We can't really help without seeing what your `client.commands` is.

Comment: I edited my question and added the index.js file, I hope it helps

Comment: Should I reference ```client.commands``` or my index.js file in my message.js?

Comment: Maybe try `module.exports = client` in index.js or define `client` in message.js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! It seems that the order in which Discord and client were (in here).

```js
module.exports = (Discord, client, msg)
```

was wrong! Instead, I swapped `Discord` around with `client` and it seems to work!

```js
module.exports = (client, Discord, msg)
```

If anyone can tell me why this happens (as I would love to learn more)
You can comment or answer!

There was also an error with the execute command which I also fixed

```js
if(cmd) {
        cmd.execute(client, msg, args, Discord);
}
```

Thanks everyone for their contribution! Really needed your help!